# How to monkey patch enums in rails 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, enums

Say I have a class that has an enum

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { active: 1, in_progress: 2, disabled: 3, ... }
end
```

and I want to patch the enum functionality so I could do

```
Course.statuses.capitalize
```

which would return a list of all statuses - capitalized and without underscores.

I have tried a couple of things but nothing seems to be helping. Any ideas?

Thanks

Below is what I tried. My experience with monkey patching is limited so not really sure if I am on the correct path or not.

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Enum
    def capitalize
      self.map{ |s| [s[0].capitalize, s[1]] }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post what you tried? And did you got any errors?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Course.status.capitalize`?

Comment: No. To get a list of statuses you have to say Course.statuses ... Let's say I want to populate a select with all available statuses, but I you want the statuses to all be capitalized. There are ways to go about doing it without monkey patching, but I thought it would be a good exercise to figure this out since I want to do this in many places and having a map function in my code bloats it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point of monkey patching this, because what you want already exists in Rails.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { active: 1, in_progress: 2, disabled: 3 }
end

Course.statuses.transform_keys{|k| k.to_s.humanize}
# => {"Active": 1, "In progress": 2, "Disabled": 3}
```